# What was the device named by fans of Star Trek?

Tags: production, props, star-trek, star-trek-beyond

[This article](http://fandom.wikia.com/articles/fans-helped-write-star-trek-beyond) and many others has a quote from *Star Trek: Beyond* writer Simon Pegg, saying that while writing the script, he reached out to Memory Alpha for help naming a device.

> We actually wrote to the Memory Alpha guys and got them to name a certain device in the movie.  I sent them a letter saying, ‘Can you come up with this for me?’  In two hours, they came back with an entire etymological history of what the thing was.  It’s beautiful.  It’s fantastic to have that support network.

Now that the movie is out, is there any indication as to what device this was?

Comment: Wait, like they made up a name? Considering the plot only had like three things, the main weapon, the camouflage or holo projectors, and her trap, that seems pretty weird.

Comment: @cde: Yeah, my assumption was that it was the weapon, but I'm looking for any proof of that. Alternatively, Scotty technobabbles at one point about turning _something_ (don't remember what) into pattern enhancers, and I'm wondering if that was it?

Comment: I think it was plasma beacon or phase beacon or something?

Comment: I think a good candidate would be the antiquated medical devices which McCoy uses to treat Spock. There's a bit of discussion from McCoy about what exactly the devices are and what they can be used for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears the answer to this question is [vokaya](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Vokaya), the Vulcan mineral that

> Spock gives a necklace of to Uhura, which is later used to locate the crew.

Beyond being mentioned in that Memory Alpha page:

> This mineral was named by Daniel C. Carlson and Harry Doddema, the founders of Memory Alpha.

It's also mentioned by Simon Pegg himself in [this video](http://fandom.wikia.com/videos/star-trek-beyond-powered-wikia), which is what finally led me to the answer.

Comment: He gave his girlfriend a radioactive tracking device?!?!

Comment: @cde that was not his intention